# Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS in virtual machine,Rider 2022.1.2 not available

Tags: asp.net, .net-6.0, ubuntu-20.04

I encountered a problem about rider under Ubuntu
Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS in virtual machine,Rider 2022.1.2 not available.
Create a class file in a folder under the Asp. net6 project,
and the rider will hang up. I try to clean up the cache of the rider,
restart the rider, restart the computer, and reinstall the rider.
It seems that there is no solution.
I even create a new virtual machine.
Doing the same operation on it will cause the same problem.
Has anyone met it? Is there any solution?
I found a similar post, but this one is under windows.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-72142
[like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVZhY.png)

Comment: I tried Rider 2022.1.2 under windows, which seems to have the same problem, but when I tried to uninstall and install the last version of 2021, namely Rider 2021.3.4, it seems to be OK. Next, I will do the same thing on Ubuntu, hoping to solve it.

Comment: As I expected, it works normally.